# UK transit visa on arrival for Italian refugee

Tags: transit-visas, lhr

I hope doing well
I have Italian refugee status travel documents 
I'm gonna travel from Stockholm to Rome via British airways but have long layover in London Heathrow 
My question is
1st Do i need transit visa to go outside airport and just explore city
2nd if i do require visa can i get that visa on arrival to UK on the airport from British border control officer

Comment: The UK does not issue visas on arrival. What is your original citizenship? https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/uk-visa-requirements-list-for-carriers/uk-visa-requirements-for-international-carriers

Comment: Pakistani but i can't use Pakistani passport i have refugee status of Italy i have to use EU travel documents

Comment: @MuhammadMousavair , FYI it costs on the order of $200 to "go from Heathrow to London to explore".  Honestly ................ I would just forget about it.  Sit at the airport, relax, and enjoy your next flight.

Comment: @Fattie How does one manage to spend $200 to go from Heathrow to London? That is more than a round trip by chauffeur-driven car. Tube is 6 pounds each way. Time is more likely to be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UK does not issue visas on arrival. You will need a visa to leave the airport. From https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/uk-visa-requirements-list-for-carriers/uk-visa-requirements-for-international-carriers

“Holders of non-national and refugee travel documents

If the passenger holds a refugee travel document issued by the UK they do not need a visa. If the passenger holds any other non-national or refugee travel document they need a visa to enter the UK.

Whether holders of non-national and refugee travel documents require a direct airside transit visa (DATV) depends on their original nationality, and whether they qualify for one of the exemptions listed”